# Call "(id)sender" method in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, methods

Here is the method I wish to call:

```
- (void)myMethod:(id)sender {
```

How would I call it? I tried:

```
[self myMethod]
```

^*error: Expected Expression before "]" token.*

I know this is a simple question, but I am new to iPhone Development

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The method takes one parameter, so you have to give it one. If you have no sender you want to give, just pass nil:

`[self myMethod:nil];`

You could also overload the method as a convenience:

```
// declarations
- (void)myMethod;
- (void)myMethod:(id)sender;

// implementations
- (void)myMethod { [self myMethod:nil]; }
- (void)myMethod:(id)sender { /* do things */ }
```

Comment: @bbum: You fixed my example while I was editing it to fix it lol. Thanks man

Answer (score 4):

Unless you wanted to send an unspecified-type object to your method you don't need the `(id)sender` portion:

```
- (void)myMethod {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass along a sender when you call it.

```
[self myMethod:something]
```

In other words, you need to have an argument to pass along when you call the method.