# macOS Do you need a window handle when you attempt to do things like minimize windows programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, appkit

C++/Objective C  and C#. Running AppKit. I am building a native plugin for a unity game.

So there is this function on AppKit:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419426-miniaturize

```
func miniaturize(_ sender: Any?)
```

I am utterly confused about what the sender portion is... Is that like some sort of window handle telling it what window to miniaturize?

When I am attempting to do these sorts of AppKit things, do I need to somehow grab a process ID (like in windows) for the window I want to be effected? Or does macOS just know what to do?

If I need a process (HWND/IntPtr/etc) how do I get that on Mac Os?

My whole goal is to programmatically open my game window whenever a notification comes in. So I want to be able to unminimized the window. I did this on windows but I need assistance for the Mac portion.

Currently I am passing just random stuff to the miniaturize function and of course nothing is happening, so I need to grab the process ID for my window somehow!! Thank you.

```
+(void)minimize:(bool)state andB:(int)handle{
    NSNumber *someNumber = @(handle);
   [NSApplication.sharedApplication.mainWindow deminiaturize:someNumber];
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call "(id)sender" method in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456115/call-idsender-method-in-xcode)

Comment: thanks, but I need to know how to grab the process handle for my game window so I can manipulate it, my question mostly revolves around this minimize function I suppose.

Comment: What do you mean by "process handle for my game window", is this `NSApplication.sharedApplication.mainWindow`? "just pass nil" would be `[NSApplication.sharedApplication.mainWindow deminiaturize:nil]`. I don't think the `sender` parameter is used.

Comment: I have it set to pass nil... I am not noticing ANYTHING at all change, and I know it is at least running. I have modified the function (earlier) to return values to prove it is working. But right now I pass nil to deminiaturize and NOTHING happens. It is very saddening.

Should I have my window up when it hits that function? Should I have it minimized? I've tried both but neither seem to have any function.

Comment: ```+(void)minimize:(bool)state andB:(int)handle{
   [NSApplication.sharedApplication.mainWindow deminiaturize:nil];
}```

Comment: Is `NSApplication.sharedApplication.mainWindow` your window and not `nil`? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Probably, `NSApplication.sharedApplication.mainWindow` is `nil` at the point where you're making that call. A minimized window won't be the main window.

Comment: You probably want to set up an outlet to your app's "main" window (in the sense you mean it) in your storyboard or NIB. Then, use that output (a.k.a. property) of your controller object (probably the app controller which is likely the same as the app delegate) to send messages to the window.

Comment: @Willeke, I will try that, what I expect to happen is that the window unminimizes itself when it detects new data in a database. This is a unity game window by the way

Comment: @KenThomases I don't know how to set an outlet to my apps main window, there is only one 'window' ever for it. My question is pretty much how do I get the outlet to the main window. This is a unity game engine window (after being built) so the whole thing is not written in objective C / whatever. It's unity. So I need to know how I can get an outlet to the main window, I have no idea what a storyboard or NIB is. I can run some commands like ```  [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:NO] ``` and they seemingly work.

Comment: @KenThomases The command MinimizeWindow works but I cannot deminimize!!!

Comment: I think you should tag your question for Unity and reword it to ask how you obtain the Cocoa window object pointer for your window in Unity.

Answer (score -2):

Okay so it was not too difficult, for deminimizing the window I used:

```
+(void)deminimize{
for(NSWindow* win in [NSApp windows])
    {
        if([win isMiniaturized])
        {
            [win deminiaturize:self];
        }
    }
}
```

I only have one window so it just finds all the pointers / whatever for me and does it this way, if you have multiple windows you might not want to do it like this.

For minimizing the window I ended up not needing this but the function is:

```
+(void)minimize{
   [NSApplication.sharedApplication.mainWindow miniaturize:nil];
}
```

For hiding and unhiding I didn't need pointers either. I just did this:

```
+(void)hide{
    [NSApp hide:nil];
}

+(void)unhide{
    [NSApp unhideAllApplications:nil]; //Just unhid all... Hopefully this doesn't cause problems! Might be able to loop through the windows like in my previous method and check if they are hidden instead of just unhiding all... Not sure if this will cause problems or not.
}
```

For bringing the screen to the front (on event / notification or whatever) I used the following after unhiding or deminimizing:

```
+(void)bringFront{
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
}
+(void)putBack{
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:NO];
}
```